Rename [argo] to [swift-argo]
Almost all questions tagged with argo are actually about argocd in violation of argo's tag wiki stating:

Apply to questions regarding thoughtbot's Swift JSON parser, Argo. For questions about the Kubernetes workflow tool, use [argocd].

It appears that it's not clear to many that they should only use argo for swift-related questions.
To make this clearer, I propose to rename argo to swift-argo and blocklist [argo` or create it as a synonym for argocd.
In addition, almost all recent argo tagged questions should be retagged with argocd or argo-workflows.
Related: Swap [argo] with [argoproj]

Are you asking to rename [argo] to [argo-swift] or [swift-argo]?

Good catch, I don't know which one is better, but both are better than the current situation

Logistically speaking, if almost all the questions are about argocd, [argo] should be merged into [argocd] (after retagging all the swift questions to [swift-argo]) to minimise work. Functionally same result, but means the manual retagging work is only around ~10 questions (based on a very quick search to count the non-[argocd] questions) instead of ~130

It's possible that some of the argocd questions should be argo-workflow instead of CD. I don't really know anything about the distinction and whether it's important.

I quickly looked it up and workflows is very separate from CD. Both from the argo project but they are entirely separate technologies. When either argocd or argo-workflows is present, argo should just be deleted. If neither is present then it's tricky. There are quite a few questions that should be argo-workflows and not argocd and vice versa. There's also at least a third distinct argo project: events. It's usually clear from the title or content which tag should be the right one.

A neutral rename would be argo to argoproj as that's the parent org of all the projects (there's even more like rollouts). This would mean the least work. Argo should then be blacklisted.
